# Dynamically assign value to ADF query

Tags: oracle-adf

dynamically give value to query
here we have two queries
1.select eno,ename,sal,deptno from emp. we use this query and create view object and

displayed in jsf page like  eno   ename   sal
                            1      aaa    bbb
                            2      ccc    ddd
2. select dname,loc from dept where deptno=:deptno. Here the :deptno comes when we
   clicking eno in jsf page(it displayed in the form of link)  the deptno of corresponding  record 
  is asigned to second query.After clicking that link the jsf page look like

```
                        eno   ename   sal   
                         1     aaa    bbb
```

dname:marketing    loc: newyork (in form type).here emp,dept names used for only example.

Comment: User, please tell us which jdev version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple master table detail form use case. If you define a view link between the emp and the dep table (emp.deptno = dept.deptno), this works out of the box. In your application module you add the dept vo as child under the emp table.

Comment: my requirement is not like that.when we run the jsf page it display one table data.In that table one column(ex:eno) data is in the form of 'links'.when we click that link the column value assign to another query and display data in the same page.(i think we right programing code for this requerement)

Answer (score 0):

You should check out view criteria. Example :
http://www.adftips.com/2010/10/adf-model-programmatically-executing.html